# Escape the * character in KDB SQL "like" queries

Tags: kdb

I have a scenario where I have data in my KDB table that contains multiple consecutive asterisk characters in a string, and I need to be able to search for that string. Suppose the string I'm searching for is `foo**bar`, the query I'd want to write is:

```
select from table where column like "foo**bar"
```

I need to escape the * characters, but I can't find in the docs how to do that. I've tried backslash and a couple of other variants without success. Presumably this must be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square brackets work as escape character with `like`

```
"foo**bar" like "foo[*][*]bar"
```

Here is a quote from [Kx wiki](https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/regex/):

```
Special characters can be matched by bracketing them
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I knew that must have been in the documentation, I just couldn't find it :)

Comment: Super helpful question and answer, thank you both....to add, I am using `"[*]*"` to flag any field with leading stars as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can use [`re2`](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/) with kdb+/q. Will always recommend using some standard regex for this task, instead of `like`